# Posting data with multiple submit buttons in PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, post

I have multiple submit buttons in my form, with multiple hidden values which are dynamically generated. Problem is that I can see correct values when looking at generated HTML source code, but submitting one buttons, submit all other values, `only on actually submitted button I have on array key-value pair more than others`. I have added index to distinct which button is submitted.

Code generating buttons is here:

```
<form action="shipment.php" method="POST"> 
            <?php 
            $index = 0;
            // get rates details array
            $rates = getRatesDetails($orderDetails);
            //$orderDetails = array();

            //$orderDetails['test_key'] = 'test_value';

            foreach ($rates as $key => $RateDetails) 
            {


            // end of PHP code
            ?>
            <div class="col-md-4">
            <button type="submit" class="shipping-option" name="orderDetails[<?php echo $index; ?>][shipping_option]" value="<?php echo $RateDetails['ServiceType']; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="orderDetails[<?php echo $index; ?>][shipping_delivery_time]" value="<?php echo $RateDetails['DeliveryTimestamp']; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="orderDetails[<?php echo $index; ?>][shipping_total_amount]" value="<?php echo $RateDetails['Amount']; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="orderDetails[<?php echo $index; ?>][shipping_total_currency]" value="<?php echo $RateDetails['Currency']; ?>">
                <ul>
                    <li>Service type: <span><?php echo $RateDetails['ServiceType']; ?></span></li>
                    <li>Estimated delivery time: <span><?php echo $RateDetails['DeliveryTimestamp']; ?></span></li>
                    <li>Total charge: <span><?php echo $RateDetails['Amount']; ?><?php echo $RateDetails['Currency']; ?></span></li>
                </ul>
            </button>
            </div>
            <?php
            $index++;

            } 
            ?>
        </form>
```

And dumped POST data is here:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [shipping_delivery_time] => 2015-11-24T08:00:00
            [shipping_total_amount] => 178.49
            [shipping_total_currency] => USD
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [shipping_option] => INTERNATIONAL_PRIORITY // actially selected option
            [shipping_delivery_time] => 2015-11-24T10:30:00
            [shipping_total_amount] => 128.91
            [shipping_total_currency] => USD
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [shipping_delivery_time] => 2015-11-27T16:30:00
            [shipping_total_amount] => 115.77
            [shipping_total_currency] => USD
        )

)
```

Actually I only need $_POST[1] array, how to achieve that? If I remove index, I only get last array value posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add new form for each input field groups:

```
    <?php 
        $index = 0;

        $rates = getRatesDetails($orderDetails);

        foreach ($rates as $key => $RateDetails) 
        {
    ?>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form action="shipment.php" method="POST"> 
            <button type="submit" class="shipping-option" name="orderDetails[<?php echo $index; ?>][shipping_option]" value="<?php echo $RateDetails['ServiceType']; ?>">Submit</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="orderDetails[<?php echo $index; ?>][shipping_delivery_time]" value="<?php echo $RateDetails['DeliveryTimestamp']; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="orderDetails[<?php echo $index; ?>][shipping_total_amount]" value="<?php echo $RateDetails['Amount']; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="orderDetails[<?php echo $index; ?>][shipping_total_currency]" value="<?php echo $RateDetails['Currency']; ?>">
            <ul>
                <li>Service type: <span><?php echo $RateDetails['ServiceType']; ?></span></li>
                <li>Estimated delivery time: <span><?php echo $RateDetails['DeliveryTimestamp']; ?></span></li>
                <li>Total charge: <span><?php echo $RateDetails['Amount']; ?><?php echo $RateDetails['Currency']; ?></span></li>
            </ul>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
        $index++;

        } 
    ?>
```